# Number of Touchpoints in GestureRecognizer

Tags: windows-8, touch, windows-runtime, windows-phone

I am using the `GestureRecognizer` to detect drag and pinch gestures.

The `ManipulationStarted`, `ManipulationUpdated` and `ManipulationCompleted` events provide the translation and scale values that are needed to pinch and drag.

However I cant figure out how to distinguish between drag (1 touch point) and pinch (2 touch points) gestures. There is no information about the number of touchpoints in `GestureRecognizer`.

How can I distinguish between drag and pinch with the `GestureRecognizer`?

Comment: Hope the following links will guide you on this [Quickstart: Touch input (Windows Store apps using C#/VB/C++ and XAML)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh465387.aspx) [Gestures, manipulations, and interactions (Windows Store apps)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh761498.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I feel it is very hacky (as most solutions seem to be for a useable WinRT app) but you can create a `List<uint>` to keep track of the number of pointers that are currently down on the screen. You would have to handle the `PointerPressed` event on whatever control you are interacting with (Let's say you are using a `Canvas`) to "capture" the pointers as they are pressed. That is where you would populate the `List<uint>`. Don't forget to clear the list at the end of the `ManipulationCompleted` event as well as any event that would fire upon the end of any gestures (like `PointerReleased`, `PointerCanceled`, and `PointerCaptureLost`). Maybe it would be a good idea to make sure the list is cleared in the `ManipulationStarted` event. Perhaps you can try that and see how that works for you.

In the `ManipulationCompleted` event, you can check if your List contains exactly 2 elements (PointerIds). If so, then you know it is a pinch/zoom.

Here is what it could look like:

```cs
private void Canvas_PointerPressed(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var ps = e.GetIntermediatePoints(null);
    if (ps != null && ps.Count > 0)
    {
        this.gestureRecognizer.ProcessDownEvent(ps[0]);
        this.pointerList.Add(e.Pointer.PointerId);
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}

private void gestureRecognizer_ManipulationCompleted(GestureRecognizer sender, ManipulationCompletedEventArgs args)
{         
    if (this.pointerList.Count == 2)
    {
       // This could be your pinch or zoom.
    }
    else
    {
       // This could be your drag.
    }

    // Don't forget to clear the list.
    this.pointerList.Clear();
}

// Make sure you clear your list in whatever events make sense.
private void Canvas_PointerReleased(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.pointerList.Clear();
}

private void Canvas_PointerCanceled(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.pointerList.Clear();
}
```

Comment: thats not such a hack IMO, but your solution lacks the pointer release events:  PointerReleased, PointerCanceled or PointerCaptureLost.

Comment: Sorry, I figured I would just post enough to make my point. But you are correct — in the PointerReleased, PointerCanceled, and PointerCaptureLost you could just clear your list. I'll update my response.

Comment: thanks, I just wanted to let you know, in case you are using your solution

Comment: Thanks. In my project, I am definitely handling all the events to properly clear my list. I hope this either worked for you or inspired you to do something completely different.

Comment: thanks, but your solution is still not correct, as you clear the list instead of removing the respective pointer

Comment: Oh, I see what you are saying. It should only be cleared upon ManipulationCompleted. But in the PointerCanceled and PointerReleased, we should just remove that PointerId from the list. Good catch.

Answer (score 2):

I have been struggling with the same question for a few hours now and it looks WinRT platform does not provide that. What it instead provides is Delta.Rotation and Delta.Scale values in addition to Delta.Translation with the arguments to ManipulationUpdated callback.

If Delta.Rotation is 0 (or very close to zero - because it is a float value) and Delta.Scale is 1 (or very close to 1), you can conclude that a pinch operation is not the case and a drag operation is being carried otherwise it is a pinch operation. It is not the best you can get but it looks it is the only availability for the time being.